How to reduce decimal places to just 2?
I have this query in BigQuery
SELECT Id, 
       AVG(VeryActiveMinutes) AS avg_very_active, 
       SUM(VeryActiveMinutes) AS total_very_active,
       SUM(SedentaryMinutes) AS total_sedentary
FROM `fit-mantra-410702.fitbit_data.dailyactivity`
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY avg_very_active DESC

The avg_very_active is returning values such as this 87.333333333333329.
I have tried to use CAST() in and outside of the AVG() to reduce to only 2 decimal places and no luck. How to I fix this?

Mathematical functions. See Rounding and truncation and use the function which better suits with your request

This question is similar to: Rounding off to two decimal places in SQL. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

have you tried CAST(AVG(VeryActiveMinutes) AS STRING FORMAT '999.99') , or similar? this returns a character string representing the value but it may not suit if you want to simply round and feed your results into another query.

Use ROUND(...,2) to return the aggregated result to 2 decimal places.
SELECT Id, 
  ROUND(AVG(VeryActiveMinutes),2) AS avg_very_active, 
  SUM(VeryActiveMinutes) AS total_very_active,
  SUM(SedentaryMinutes) AS total_sedentary
FROM `fit-mantra-410702.fitbit_data.dailyactivity`
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY avg_very_active DESC


I swear I had tried ROUND haha, but I must have misused it somehow. But that worked, I appreciate it!

Great. Glad to help. Please upvote my answer.
